# How to disable autopostback for a html button?

Tags: popup, postback

I want to show a popup on click of a button. I am able to achieve it but I was not able to stop autopostback. The pop-up is displayed and page gets posted back automatically.
Need help. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the LinkButton's OnClientClick property:

```
protected void lnkConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write("Postback!");
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkConfirm" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Do Postback?');"
    OnClick="lnkConfirm_Click">Postback</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're doing something like this in Javascript to open the popup:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.open('...');" ... />
```

All you need to do is add "return false;" to the end of your Javascript call to prevent the postback from occurring, leaving you with something like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.open('...'); return false;" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

use **return false;** under function call on click.
For example

```
onclick="dosomthing(); return false;"
```